# Flush PostgreSQL log files (Close & reopen files) without restarting postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get PostgreSQL to flush it's log files and reopen them, without having to restart? I have tried to send the HUP signal, but that doesn't do it. I accidentally have a large postgres log file, which i have `rm`ed to delete, but postgres still has the file open, so the disk space isn't freed.

I have PostgreSQL 9.5 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04

Answer (score 0):

As of Postgres 12, there is a command for rotating log files:

```
pg_ctl logrotate [-D datadir] [-s]
```

See also [pg_ctl documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/app-pg-ctl.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want your log files be there periodically. You can try `cron`.

With this commands
`crontab -e`

Then write

`# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 6 * * * rm /somewhere/your/postgresql.log`

Then save it.

`sudo service cron restart`

This means your system will remove the log at 6:00 A.M. everyday.

Comment: That won't flush the logs and make postgres open a new file. I have done just that (removed the log file), and it hasn't changed the disk usage.

Comment: Or you can read [postgresql log manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/logfile-maintenance.html). Use `pg_ctl start > /dev/null` to redirect the log to null.